# Updating itemrenderer dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, combobox, itemrenderer, dataprovider

I am creating an opensource application for managing environmental resources in my county.

I have a problem on a dataprovider for an itemrenderer (combobox) i am using on a datagrid.
The application works, but I get a warning saying the itemrenderer dataprovider will not be reassigned data on its update with a setter. Even if I do not need to reassign the combobox itemrenderer dataprovider, for a matter of best practice I would like to solve this warning.

This is the usual code I use for getting dataprovider data as an array collection populated from the result of a web service in the parentDocument of the itemrenderer:

```
    //set farmers arrayCollection values for combobox itemrenderer
    [Bindable]
    private var _acFarmers:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection;
    public function set acFarmers(acFarmers:ArrayCollection):void{
        _acFarmers=acFarmers;

    }
    //get machines ArrayCollection values
    public function get acFarmers():ArrayCollection{
        return _acFarmers;
    }
```

This is the code for the datagrid itemrenderer (showing only the interested column of the datagrid):

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Agricoltore" dataField="farmerId" width="200" rendererIsEditor="true" editable="false">

            <mx:itemRenderer>

                <fx:Component id="cmpCmbFarmers">

                        <mx:HBox>

                        <s:ComboBox width="200" 
                                    id="cmbFarmers"
                                    dataProvider="{outerDocument.acFarmers}" 
                                    labelField="companyName" 
                                    change="onSelectionChange(event)"

                                    >
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
                                    import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
                                    import mx.events.ListEvent;

                                    private var _ownerData:Object;

                                    private function setSelected():void {

                                    }

                                    override public function set data(value:Object):void{
                                        if(value != null)  {
                                            super.data=value;
                                            _ownerData=value;

                                            if(value.collectingMachineId!==null){
                                                for each(var dp:Object in cmbFarmers.dataProvider){
                                                    var dpFarmerId:String=dp.farmerId
                                                    var dataFarmerId:String=value.farmerId;
                                                    if(dpFarmerId==dataFarmerId){
                                                        cmbFarmers.selectedItem=dp;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                cmbFarmers.selectedIndex=0;
                                                data.farmerId=cmbFarmers.selectedItem.farmerId;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                                    import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

                                    protected function onSelectionChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
                                    {

                                        data.farmerId=cmbFarmers.selectedItem.farmerId;
                                    }     



                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            </s:ComboBox>

                        </mx:HBox>


            </fx:Component> 
            </mx:itemRenderer>

            </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

This code works if I call the itemrenderer service to get combobox data BEFORE calling the datagrid data service and setting the datagrid arraycollection at re response of the service.

BUT a warning is displayed because the combobox dataprovider will not get changes after a set function on its dataprovider (_acFarmers).

This is the only warning I have on an entire project but i did not manage how to solve it.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `[Bindable]` metatag above your setter instead of above `_acFarmers`. Because right now your `acFarmers` property is not the source for data binding.

Or better use just public variable instead of getter and setter since you didn't implement other actions in them.

[Link about databinding](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dataChangeEvent
you can use the dataChange event with an item renderer or item editor. Flex dispatches the dataChange event every time the data property changes.

```
<mx:ItemRenderer dataChange="someFunction()">
```

or

```
dataToDisplay.addEventListener( FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE, dataChange );
```